# How to Change Font Size of my Pdf document using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

We are unable to change font size of pdf generated from below code anybody can help us?

We would like to convert that html file into pdf after changing the font size.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

protected void ConvertToPDFNow()
{

 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        print.RenderControl(w);

         string htmWrite = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";


    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.pdf");

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    htmWrite = Regex.Replace(htmWrite, "</?(a|A).*?>", "");

    htmWrite = htmWrite.Replace("\r\n", "");

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(htmWrite);

    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    //Creating Document of A4 Size
    HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(doc);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);

    doc.Open();

    try
    {
    //rendering Html File                
   parser.Parse(reader);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {                   
    }
    finally
    {
        doc.Close();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

try to apply stylesheet:

```
...
    var style = new StyleSheet();
    style.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", "12px");
    parser.SetStyleSheet(style);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

The C# code below works fantastically to change itextpdf font size:

```
var style = new StyleSheet();
style.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", "8px");
HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlworker.SetStyleSheet(style);
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitor, when you add some explanation to your intension.